# Delete Multiple Azure Data Factory Pipeline

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, azure-powershell, azure-data-factory, azureportal

I want to delete 50+ ADF pipelines linked to Azure Devops GIT. We can do it manually via Azure Front-end, but it's a tedious task. I have tried deleting it via Powershell but powershell can only delete the pipelines which present under DataFactory(PFA the screenshot) mode whereas it is not impacting pipelines linked to Azure DevOps GIT.

[image]

Can anyone suggest any better approach to do this activity ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want them out of git, you can create a feature branch from the ADF editor. Then use Visual Studio or any git repo navigator to pull that branch to your local file system. Manually delete the files and then push back to git and do a pull request to merge back into your master.

If you really want to purge them completely, you can do the same manual deletion upon your ADF publish branch too.

Answer (score 0):

I accomplished the task of deleting pipeline by :-

1. Creating a clone of the Dev branch in my local Visual studio.
2. By deleting all .json file (corresponding to the pipeline I wanted to delete) from newly cloned local branch.
3. Commit, Sync and Push the change to Dev GIT branch.

This is the easiest way I could find to delete 50+ pipelines in one shot.